# How to share code intelligence between several blocks of the same module?

Tags: php, module, blocks, magento-2.1, best-practice

How to share code intelligence between several blocks of the same module ? Is there a "Magento way" to do this ? or should I simply use Traits to share some functions between a given module class ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use traits or a base block class from which you can extend your blocks or you can use a helper.
In my opinion there is no a 'Magento way' of doing this. Use what suits your module better